# Is it correct to say, "what would he likes to eat"?

Tags: modal-verbs

Is it correct to say "What would he likes to eat?"

If I ask to my friend for another friend's choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would he **likes** to eat?

Let's look at the structure.

> [What] **would** *(modal verb)* he *(subject)* **likes** to eat?

This sentence is inverted since it's a question and *what* is a question word. Now, if you change it back to its normal uninverted form, it'll look like this :

> He *(subject)* **would** *(modal verb)* **likes** to eat.

The verb **likes** in this sentence is not considered as a verb but as a part of the modal verb **would**. So therefore, the verb **likes** should be in the original form (infinitive form), which is **like**. The correct sentence is :

> What would he **like** to eat?

More information :

[Would](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/would.html)

[Basic question structure](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-questions_structure.htm)

Answer (score 2):

No, it’s grammatically incorrect.

When using a modal, the verb always takes the bare infinitive form.